# Probability using mean and SD

Tags: probability, statistics

Mean = 500
SD = 100

find probability that 5 RV are below 600:

i figure i should just find the probability that 1 is below 600 and then do sum of probabilitys?

$$P(x \leq600) = P\left(z \leq \frac{600-500}{100}\right) = P(z\leq 1)$$

I know i am missing something because, it cannot be 1. please help me.

edit:
Normal Distribution

Comment: You need to know the form of the distribution. Is it normal?

Comment: Are the random variables independent?

Comment: The question doesnt say, but they represent people... so i will assume yes.

Comment: What do you know about probabilities of independent events?

Comment: not sure i understand your question. P(A and B) = P(A) · P(B), but im not at that point yet, because i cannot find out the P(x <= 600)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will assume that the five random variables are all **normally distributed** with the given mean and standard deviation, and are **independent**.

The probability that such a normal random variable is $\le 600$ is, as you know, equal to the probability that a standard normal $Z$ is $\le 1$.  This is approximately $0.8413$.  You can find a [table of the standard normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table) in many places.

The probability that all five random variables are $\le 600$ is therefore $\approx(0.8413)^5$.

Comment: How do you know that Z <= 1 = 0.8413? That is the part that i am missing.

Comment: You look at a table of the standard normal. There, $\Pr(Z\le z)$ is given for a wide range of values.  Or else one can get the information from many pieces of software, such as most spreadsheet programs. You can find a standard normal table by Googling standard normal table.

Comment: ...and in case you don't know how to convert your variable into standard normal one, just use the fact that if $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^{2})$, then $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, so in your case, that would boil down to finding $\mathbb{P}(Z\leq 1)$, where $Z=\frac{X-500}{100}$.